# Неправильная работа массива в c++ (или мои кривые руки)

Tags: c++, массивы

По каким то причинам последний элемент массива равен -858993460

```
{
    int i[10];
    i[0] = 1; i[9] = 1;
    for (int u = 1; u < 8; u++) {
        i[u] = 0;
    }
    for (int u = 0; u < 9; u++) {
        cout << i[u] << endl; 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В теории он должен быть равен 1.

Comment: `system("pause")` на данный момент для меня является якорем, который дает увидеть вывод. Программа проста как 2*2, так что не вижу смысла добавлять сюда какие либо сложные методы для вывода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, вы присвоили нулевой и девятый элементы.

В цикле - от первого по седьмой.

А выводите - от нулевого по восьмой включительно.

Но в восьмом - неинициализированном - может быть любой мусор. В теории и на практике тоже :)

Что и наблюдаем...

Comment: Теперь работает. Стоит быть внимательнее :)